# Python-Only executes first print

Tags: python

```
animals=["zebras", "dogs", "cats", "snakes", "insects"]

A=0
B=1
while B<= (len(animals)-1): 
    if animals[A] > animals[B]:
        animals= [animals[B]] + [animals[A]] + animals[B+1:]
        B= B + 1
        print(B)
        print(animals)

print("test- Will this not print as well?")
```

> Okay thanks, that's seems to have worked.  I do have one question still, however: how come it printed B but not the next print statement: print(animals)?
> When I comment out the print B statement then the print(animals)
> works.
>
> this is the output I get when I run the code (as is) with the while loop not terminating.
>
> output:
> 2

Comment: `'cats' > 'insects' == False`, so it gets stuck after 2 iterations in the `while` loop, never entering the `if` again

Comment: Are you sure you updated your code? When I run it I get the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not print because you are forever stuck in your while loop.

The first time it runs, it will check

```
"zebras" > "dogs"
```

which is true, then it will print

```
2
['dogs', 'zebras', 'cats', 'snakes', 'insects']
```

then again,

```
"zebras" > "cats"
```

also true, prints

```
3
['cats', 'dogs', 'snakes', 'insects']
```

then it gets

```
['insects', 'cats']
```

but when it now tries to check if animals[0] > animals[3], it gets issues, returning False because animals[3] does not exist. Ergo your infinite loop.

Comment: Okay thanks, that's seems to have worked. I forgot I changed the loop so it might not terminate. I do have  one question still, however: how come it printed B but not the next print statement: print(animals)? When I comment out the print B statement then the print animals (works).

Comment: It prints both statements

Comment: @daborediowan Well, it depends on the changes you made, please make an edit to your question so we can see.